# How to get the proper key to use expire_fragment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I use fragment caching in Rails 4.x.

I specify my own key using something like this in my view:

```
<% cache "my-key" %>
      html
<% end %>
```

This produces a key similar to this in my Redis database:

```
views/my-key/dca9add42d461d4c76103c08d12a6571
```

When I want to expire this key, I use the expire_fragment command in a controller like so:

```
expire_fragment("my-key")
```

But this command only produces a cache key like so:

```
views/my-key
```

What I don't understand is, what is the `/dca9add42d461d4c76103c08d12a6571` part?

How does the original `cache` command not produce it, or how can I reproduce the `/dca9add42d461d4c76103c08d12a6571` suffix when I want to expire the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is by design, or whether there is a bug in Rails. But what is happening is the suffix `/dca9add42d461d4c76103c08d12a6571` that's added to the end of the cache key when I use the cache command in my views, is a **digest**, which you can skip by calling cache like so:

```
<% cache("my-key", { :skip_digest: true }) %>
    html
<% end %>
```

That way the suffix (digest) gets left off the key.

Now where I think a possible bug (?) is coming in, is that the `expire_fragment` command *doesn't* add the **digest** to the end of the key - so I never actually end up expiring my fragments.

So my answer for now - is to use `:skip_digest: true` if I want to manually expire them.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Rails documentation, you can just pass in the key as a string:

```
expire_fragment('my-key')
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching

If you're doing it from the command line, you might have to go through whatever controller the view is rendered by:

```
MyController.new.expire_fragment 'my-key'
```

Comment: The documentation isn't very good around this - 'cos they also say to use fragment_cache_key that will create a key like the key used by the cache command. However - there's still the /dca9add42d461d4c76103c08d12a6571 suffix that the cache command adds, but that the fragment_cache_key and expire_fragment combo doesn't.

Comment: I also see that internally expire_fragment uses fragment_cache_key anyway - so no need to use the fragment_cache_key method myself. However - this still doesn't expire my key, as when I write the key it add that damn suffix to the end ... an etag? So I never get to the actual key I need to expire. I'll edit my question.

Comment: the stuff at the end is a hash based on the template. so that when you change the template it expires the cache.